# Count Integers satisfying the conditions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms

Given some constraints ,I need to find possible ways that these conditions are satisfied.

I need to find four POSITIVE integers a,b,c,d such that ad-bc > 0 and also a+d=N for a given value of N.

How many ways can be their to assgin values to these four variables to satisfy these conditions.

EXAMPLE : 
Say N=3 then here answer is 2 as their are 2 ways : (1,1,1,2) and (2,1,1,1).

Comment: Starting with $n=3$, there are 2,11,30,60,100,163,242,350,470,627,814,1034,1288,1569,1912,2296,2698,3193,... ways.  I do not think a closed form expression is currently possible (see Dirichlet's divisor problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function).

Comment: @MatthewConroy If not any closed form expression ,What can be a algorithm to do so?

Comment: Please close this question as it is a ongoing contest problem.
http://www.codechef.com/APRIL14/problems/CNPIIM

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(n)$ be the number of positive integer 4-tuples $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, $ad-bc>0$, and $a+d=n$.

Then 
$$
g(n)= \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \sum_{b,c: bc<a(n-a)} 1
= \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} D(a(n-a))-\tau(a(n-a))
$$
where $D(x)$ is the summatory divisor function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function)
$$
D(x) = \sum_{1\le i \le x} \tau(i) = \sum_{ij\le x} 1
$$
and $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Since $D(x)$ has no closed form expression, you are unlikely to get a closed form here, I think, but $g(n)$ is easily calculated directly for fairly small $n$.